# Gap in the middle of type on double truck ad

Tags: text

I collect old car advertising and noticed on a double truck ad for a 1968 VW Bus the headline when laid flat reads-" New Impr oved Box "- I assume this is to remain readable in the middle of a magazine with a huge page count(I bet publishers would love this problem in today's market)What is the gap in the word improved referred to as? I am not a graphics professional so forgive my ignorance

Answer (score 2):

The two pages treated as one layout is called a Double Page Spread. The space between the letters is called Kerning and the part of the double page spread that gets obscured due to the binding is called the Gutter.

The designer of your example increased the kerning between the r and the o to make it more readable across the gutter of the spread.

Comment: Gutters refer to the white space between and around columns of text. Though the space between the two pages is *also* a gutter, the term doesn't refer specifically to that space.

Comment: Ooops...I have to take my previous comment back. After researching a bit more, I found out that some people do use the term 'gutter' to refer specifically to the space between the two pages, while others use the term 'gutter' to refer to space between columns of text. I learned the latter. (I suppose we should call them *page* gutters and *column* gutters to be clear...)